# how to set timeout on javascript echo

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I am using this js for an echo and normally, it disappears after 5 sec. How can i force for this echo to stay for 10 sec?

```
 var hulla = new hullabaloo();
hulla.send("File already exists! Do you want to overwrite it?<br /><a class='btn btn-primary' href=''>Yes</a>", "warning");
```

Comment: You will need to show some more code. Show what `hullabaloo` does. It likely has a `setTimeout` in it or something.

Comment: no idea unless you show us what kind of object is created by `new hullabaloo()` - in particular what its `send` method does. (Or link to some documentation if it's a 3rd-party library.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor allows you to pass in additional settings, in this case `delay`, to change to 10 seconds:

```
var hulla = new hullabaloo({ delay: 10000 });
```

More info: https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Notification-Plugin-Bootstrap-4-Hullabaloo.html

Comment: yes i agree, the delay is set default to 5000. But only for this, i want to make an exception. `var hulla = new hullabaloo({ delay: 10000 });` takes not the 10 sec , but still 5

Comment: Then sounds like a bug in hullabaloo - get in contact with the developer

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var hulla = new hullabaloo({ delay: 10000 });
hulla.send("File already exists! Do you want to overwrite it?<br /><a class='btn btn-primary' href=''>Yes</a>", "warning");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to the jQuery plugin, it appears to have a corresponding option that can be set as follows:

```
$.hulla.options.delay = 10000
```